# Run time error 7: out of memory

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I was recently adding a new query to a routine when i unexpectedly encountered the 'run time error 7: out of memory' error.  I am trying to understand how this has come about and why.  Is it fixable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i also encounter that error when i use a large amount of data. what i did was, i divided the records chunk by chunk just to execute the query successfully.

the link below could also be some help

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/161255

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by dividing the records?  By the way, I have copied my code into another database and the problem is no longer present but I am wondering if it is just hiding and waiting to lurk it's evil head.

Comment: have you tried to repair and compact your database? i also suggest to open then close your database regularly to release the allocated memory

Answer (score 2):

This can be when the microsoft application has allocated all of the memory it can.  Usually just closing the application and reopening it releases the memory and sorts the problem out.  I experience this when I am refreshing large data sets linked to pivot tables.  Sometimes I have to refresh the pivots 1 by 1 saving and closing in between.  I even created a macro to do that for me.